# compare values in two columns and recode in R or awk

Tags: r, awk

I have file in the below format with few rows shown below.

```
<N2>    AS  12/13:2:-1000.00,-25.73     13/13:2:-272.09,-12.81
<N2>    AS  6/6:2:-1000.00,-19.88   8/8:2:-211.51,-5.98
<N0>    AS  4/4:0:2:-218.21,-11.95  4/4:2:-208.55,-11.01
<N0>    AS  0/0:2:-1000.00,-16.68   0/0:2:-294.18,-10.45
<N0>    AS  0/1:2:-1000.00,-16.68   0/1:2:-294.18,-10.45
<N0>    AS  1/1:2:-1000.00,-16.68   1/1:2:-294.18,-10.45
```

The first element in $3 need to be compared with first element in $4 separted by ":" and recode using only 0 and 1 values. The logic for all four possible cases of comparison for the example data is illustrated here:

```
when only one value differ between the two elements then change to 0/0  and 0/1    
when both values differ between the two elements then change to 0/0  and 1/1  
when both values are same and non-zero  between the two elements  then change to 1/1  and  1/1
when both the values are arleady coded in 0 and 1 do not change them.
```

In the example data as per the above logic, compare the first element in $3 with $4.

```
12/13  and  13/13 have one value in common separated by "/" so change then to 0/0 and 1/1
6/6 and 8/8 both values separated by "/" differ between $3 and $4, so change to 0/0 and 1/1
4/4 and 4/4 both values separated by "/" are same between $3 and $4 and non-zero values so change to   1/1 and 1/1
```

Do not change if the values are already coded on 0 and 1.

So the output for the above example looks like below:

```
<N2>    AS  0/0:2:-1000.00,-25.73   0/1:2:-272.09,-12.81
<N2>    AS  0/0:2:-1000.00,-19.88   1/1/0:2:-211.51,-5.98
<N0>    AS  1/1:0:2:-218.21,-11.95  1/1:2:-208.55,-11.01
<N0>    AS  0/0:2:-1000.00,-16.68   0/0:2:-294.18,-10.45
<N0>    AS  0/1:2:-1000.00,-16.68   0/1:2:-294.18,-10.45
<N0>    AS  1/1:2:-1000.00,-16.68   1/1:2:-294.18,-10.45
```

Any possible solution in awk or R?

Comment: @AndreElrico anyone could downvote not a problem, I feel like i conveyed it to the best i could but may be not.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to give some meaning to these numbers so that people can understand _why_ you want to do what you want to do. Also explaining the rules would probably work better in general terms than by describing example cases.

Comment: Also, on row 2 col 4 you have `8/8/0`, which is 3 values, but all the rules are specified in terms of a comparison of a pair of two values. Is this a data error or how would you handle the 2-3 comparison?

Comment: it is a typo, thanks for pointing it.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it general.

Comment: [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: is the first value and first pair always "smaller" like in your example???? so is `$3: 17:15 ` and `$:4 15:13` possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible to have such values.

Comment: shouldn't `12/13  and  13/13` yield  `0/0 and 0/1`?

Comment: yes, it should and the below solution does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in R.

**Data:**

```
df1<-
data.table::fread("<N2>    AS  12/13:2:-1000.00,-25.73     13/13:2:-272.09,-12.81
<N2>    AS  6/6:2:-1000.00,-19.88   8/8/0:2:-211.51,-5.98
                  <N0>    AS  4/4:0:2:-218.21,-11.95  4/4:2:-208.55,-11.01
                  <N0>    AS  0/0:2:-1000.00,-16.68   0/0:2:-294.18,-10.45
                  <N0>    AS  0/1:2:-1000.00,-16.68   0/1:2:-294.18,-10.45
                  <N0>    AS  1/1:2:-1000.00,-16.68   1/1:2:-294.18,-10.45",sep=" ",header=F) %>% setDF
```

**Code:** Create a function that does the work for you and load libraries:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
fun1 <- function(df_in) {
    vals <- lapply(df_in,function(x){sub("(\\d+/\\d+).*","\\1",x,perl=T) %>% strsplit("/") %>% lapply(as.numeric)})
    newvals<-
        mapply(function(x,y){
            if(all(c(x,y) %in% 0:1)) list(paste0(x,collapse="/"),paste0(y,collapse="/")) else {
                u = -abs(x-y)<=-1;
                return(
                    case_when(
                        identical(u,c(T,F)) ~ list("0/0","0/1"),
                        identical(u,c(F,T)) ~ list("0/0","0/1"),
                        identical(u,c(T,T)) ~ list("0/0","1/1"),
                        identical(u,c(F,F)) ~ list("1/1","1/1"),
                        TRUE    ~ list("Error","Error")
                    )
                )
            } },x=vals[[1]],y=vals[[2]])
    return(
        list(
            paste0(unlist(newvals[1,]),sub("\\d+/\\d+","",df_in[[1]])),
            paste0(unlist(newvals[2,]),sub("\\d+/\\d+","",df_in[[2]]))
        )
    )
}
```

**Call function:** On column-numbers that need to change:

```
df1[,3:4] %<>% fun1
```

**Result:**

```
#> df1
#    V1 V2                     V3                    V4
#1 <N2> AS  0/0:2:-1000.00,-25.73  0/1:2:-272.09,-12.81
#2 <N2> AS  0/0:2:-1000.00,-19.88 1/1/0:2:-211.51,-5.98
#3 <N0> AS 1/1:0:2:-218.21,-11.95  1/1:2:-208.55,-11.01
#4 <N0> AS  0/0:2:-1000.00,-16.68  0/0:2:-294.18,-10.45
#5 <N0> AS  0/1:2:-1000.00,-16.68  0/1:2:-294.18,-10.45
#6 <N0> AS  1/1:2:-1000.00,-16.68  1/1:2:-294.18,-10.45
```

Comment: The data posted is just sample data and it not limited to those values like 4,6,8,12,13 as shown in the example. The original data has ~10K rows and finite values from 1 to 100 in $3 and $4

Comment: OP modified. The logic given there is the general rule for transformation which should apply to all values in the dataset.

Comment: The solution works as expected. I mean to say that in the R code the exact values in the test data are hardcoded eg: `all(u == c(12,13)` . But the original data can have different values like 16/17  where this does not work.

Comment: Now i understood the problem. Im not saying that 12 or 13 should be repalced by 0 or 1.  I need to compare 12/13 with 13/13. Here one value differs, then this pair should be recoded to 0/0 and 0/1. There could be a different pair 15/16  and 16/17 where again one value differ between these two and this pair needs to be recoded to 0/0 and 0/1

Comment: with your second: `"$3=13/12 and $4=15/13 only one element differs between these two and in this they should be replaced by 0/0 and 0/1"` - How does just one element differ here? 13 is different from 15 and 12 is different from 13. So two elements differ. I have updated my function for the last time. Hope this helps.

Comment: It still fails in the following two cases. 1) when $3=15/14 and $4=9/17 both the values differ and so it should be replaced as by 0/0 and 1/1. But it replaces with "Error". This is fixed by adding u >= 2 ~ list("0/0","1/1") in the code. 2) when $3=13/12 and $4=13/13 only one element differs between these two and in this they should be replaced by 0/0 and 0/1 but instead it is replaced by 0/0 and 1/1. COuld you hint to fix with the later case